How to get `requestId` for AWS Lambda synchronous invocation?
I am invoking an AWS Lambda function through the official aws cli, as
aws lambda invoke --function-name [name] --payload [payload] [outfile]

A successful invocation looks something like:
{
    "StatusCode": 200,
    "ExecutedVersion": "$LATEST"
}

However, I am unable to find the requestId that lambda assigns my execution. I need this requestId to be able to efficiently filter my function logs in CW as I have already enabled JSON-based structured logging for my function which helpfully adds a requestId field to all my log lines.
I have already tried/thought about following approaches:

Use the --log-type TAIL flag in the CLI to directly get the b64-encoded logs. This has the limitation that the output is limited to 4KB so if my function writes more than 4KB logs I am helpless.
Instrument my function code to return requestId in the response which will then be saved to [outfile]. This is okay, but only works for successful invocations. If my function fails due to any reason, I will not be able to get the correct response. Ironically, the requestId is most helpful in these cases only.
Add a custom UUID to my lambda's input payload and instrument my logging library to also log that as a field with every log line. This almost works, except that I have no control over lambda's system log lines (the START, END & REPORT lines) which will still contain the lambda's original requestId and not my custom UUID.


doesn't the response contain ResponseMetadata ?

Which ResponseMetadata are you talking about? I don't see any attribute. In fact, even if I look at the API reference for Invoke, there's nothing of that sort.

You are actually not helpless if your function has more than 4KB logs. With Tail option, it will show last 4KB of logs, but you have a Request ID at the end of the log file (END and REPORT lines) so to achieve what you need, you can grep through the response log and get the last line that contains the RequestId.
aws lambda invoke --function-name [name] [outfile] --log-type Tail --query 'LogResult' output text --cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out | base64 --decode | grep 'RequestId' | tail -1


This is actually a bit more complicated if the intention is to programatically obtain this requestId as the actual log output depends upon whether JSON-based logging is enabled for lambda system logs in its configuration or not. It also feels a bit hacky, to transfer a 4KB payload just to obtain a requestId. We may end up doing it anyways, but only if there's really no other option.

@sarthak-ag there's one more option, but it's more hacky. If you call with --debug flag, you will get RequestId in the debug logs, but that's worse option

Check if it's available in the returned HTTP response headers. It's definitely present somewhere because if you run the awscli with --debug option you'll see that it debug logs the RequestId.

@jarmod we don't have access to http response headers through the CLI, or even SDK I believe.

You could potentially modify the Lambda function to return the request id in its response payload, given that you're invoking the Lambda function synchronously. The request id is available in the context parameter passed into the Lambda function.
